# if $ H $ is a locally compact subgroup of a topological group $ G $, then $ H $ is closed in $ G $

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

**Theorem:** If $ H $ is a locally compact subgroup of a topological group $ G $, then  $ H $ is closed in $ G $.

**proof:**  Let $ K $ be the closure of $ H $ in $G $. Then $ K $ is a subgroup of $ G $. Since $ H$ is a dense locally compact subset of $ K $, also $ H $ is open in $ K $. However, an open subgroup of a topological group is closed, so $ H = K $.

> **1: Why is $H $ open in $ K $?**
>
> **2: Where do we use locally compactness ?**

The next question is not related to above text, please help me.

We know that  if $ H $ is a discrete subgroup of a topological group $ G $, then $ H $ is closed in $ G $.

**So, is it right to say:**

> 3: Every discrete subgroup $ H $ of a countably compact quasi topological group
> $ G $ is finite.

Comment: This requires $G$ to be Hausdorff.

Answer (score 5):

Any locally compact dense subspace of a Hausdorff space is open.  Indeed, suppose $H$ is locally compact and dense in a Hausdorff space $K$.  Let $x\in H$, and choose an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $H$ whose closure $C$ is compact.  We can write $U=V\cap H$ for some $V$ that is open in $K$.  Since $C$ is compact and $K$ is Hausdorff, $C$ is also closed in $K$.  Thus $V\setminus C$ is open in $K$.  But $V\setminus C$ does not intersect $H$ since $V\cap H=U\subseteq C$, so since $H$ is dense $V\setminus C$ must be empty.  That is, $V\subseteq C$ and in particular $V\subseteq H$.  Thus $H$ contains an open neighborhood (in $K$) of $x$, and since $x\in H$ was arbitrary, $H$ is open in $K$.

As for your last question, that's correct.  The argument works just as well for quasitopological groups, since it's still true that an open subgroup is closed.