# Locally compact valued field is complete?

Tags: complete-spaces, local-field, topological-rings

In J. P. Serre's book Local Fields, in the proof of one proposition it says:

If $K$ is locally compact, it is complete.

How did he deduce that? As far as I know, there is no correlation between locally compactness and completion. So I assume he used the fact that $K$ is a valued field, but how?

Answer (score 8):

You are right: a locally compact metric space isn't necessarily complete. But every metrizable locally compact group *is* complete.

Comment: Is there a reference for this please?

Comment: @PunkZebra Check theorem 4.5 from [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606794.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $K$ be a locally compact topological field and $\overline{K}$ its completion. Then $K$ is a subfield of $\overline K$, [and hence closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419181/if-h-is-a-locally-compact-subgroup-of-a-topological-group-g-then-h) (so in particular, complete.)