# Discrete subgroup must be closed?

Tags: topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

The question is :
Let $G$ be a locally compact topological subgroup and $H$ is a discrete subgroup of $G$ (i.e. the hereditary topology of $H$ is discrete). Is $H$ always closed?

---

I think the answer is “yes”. I want to prove that if $G$ is a locally compact and $H$ is discrete subgroup then $H\cap K$ is finite for every compact set $K\subseteq G$. It is clear that this will implies $H$ is closed. But I still don’t know how to prove it. If you could prove this claim, it also will be a nice answer for me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you prove it if $G$ is a Lie group?

Comment: @JairTaylor I can prove for some matrix group with metric structure, for example $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. But still can’t prove for general Lie groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true if $G$ is $T_1$ (which implies it is Hausdorff, see [How to show that topological groups are automatically Hausdorff?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269853/how-to-show-that-topological-groups-are-automatically-hausdorff))

Since $H$ is discrete, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $1$ such that $U\cap H=\left\{1\right\}$. Take $V$ another neighborhood of $1$ s.t. $V^{-1}V\subseteq U$.

Let $g\in G\setminus H$. We need to prove that there is a neighborhood of $g$ which does not intersect $H$. If $gV\cap H=\varnothing$ then we are done.

Suppose then $gV\cap H\neq\varnothing$. Take $h\in gV\cap H$. Let us prove that $gV\cap H=\left\{h\right\}$. Given $k\in gV\cap H$, we have
\begin{align*}
k^{-1}h
&\in (gV)^{-1}(gV)\\
&=V^{-1}g^{-1}gV\\
&=V^{-1}V\\
&\subseteq U\end{align*}
and also $k^{-1}h\in H$, so $k^{-1}h=1$, which means that $k=h$.

So $gV\cap H=\left\{h\right\}$. But $g\not\in H$ by definition, so $g\neq h$. Since $G$ is $T_1$, there exists another neighborhood $W$ of $1$ s.t. $h\not\in gW$. Therefore $gW\cap H=\varnothing$.

---

If $G$ is not $T_1$ then this is not true, for in this case $H=\left\{1\right\}$ is not closed but it is discrete.

Answer (score 1):

The result is true more generally if $G$ is a Hausdorff topological space, without any assumption of local compactness.

Any discrete subgroup $H$ of a Hausdorff $G$ is closed. Indeed, $H$ is locally compact (for every $x\in H$ the singleton $\{x\}$ is a compact neighborhood of $x$). And a locally compact subgroup of a Hausdorff topological group is closed, as shown for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419181).

Comment: It‘s very helpful, thank you.